# How can I reduce redundancy by only defining the __add__ method only once?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading

```
class Ferrari:
    def __init__(self,no_cars):
        self.no_cars=no_cars
    def __add__(self,other):
        return self.no_cars+other.no_cars

class Jaquar:
    def __init__(self,no_cars):
        self.no_cars=no_cars
    def __add__(self,other):
        return self.no_cars+other.no_cars


f1=Ferrari(5)
j1=Jaquar(10)
total_cars= f1 + j1
print(total_cars)
```

I am trying to add two objects of different classes with operator overloading but it seems if I change the order of the operands, I will get an error that is why I have to define the `__add__` method in both the classes so even if I change the order I will still get the same output but the code seems redundant and I cannot figure out any other way to do it. What can be the best alternative to it so my code is not redundant?

Comment: Why have you defined two different classes? Just define a single `Auto` class.

Comment: Or make them subclasses of an `Auto` class, and put the comment methods in the superclass.

Comment: That is not my concern here, my main objective is that how can I add objects of two different classes and make sure even if I change the order of the operands, my code doesn't run into any errors but at the same time I do not want to write __add__ method in both the classes as it promotes redundancy

Comment: You either have to use the same class or duplicate the code.

Answer (score 1):

Define the `__radd__` method, it handles the arguments being in the opposite order.

```
class Ferrari:
    def __init__(self,no_cars):
        self.no_cars=no_cars
    def __add__(self,other):
        return self.no_cars+other.no_cars
    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self + other
```